# How do I check if a var is NaN in ruby?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, conditional-statements, nan

How do I check in an if statement if a number is the "NaN" value?  I thought this would work

```
2.4.0 :003 >   i = Float::NAN
 => NaN
2.4.0 :004 > puts "hi" if i
hi
 => nil
2.4.0 :005 > puts "hi" if i != Float::NAN
hi
 => nil
2.4.0 :006 > i
 => NaN
2.4.0 :007 > puts "hi" if i == Float::NAN
 => nil
```

But as you can see, despite the fact I set "i" to "NaN", I'm getting the baffling output above.

Comment: `NaN` is not equal to anything, not even to `NaN`. That's just what the spec says. The reason for this is: `NaN` is not a number (duh!), it is a condition that tells you something is not going the way you think it is. There can be many reasons for this condition, therefore it was simply decided that nothing would ever be equal to `NaN`. `NaN` is the equivalent of "I don't know" … well, if you don't know, then you also don't know that it is equal! (In a system of three-valued logic, `NaN == anything` would probably be "I don't know" instead of `false`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> despite the fact I set "i" to "NaN", I'm getting the baffling output above.

This is the correct behaviour, in accordance with the [IEEĘ754 specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985). You'll find the same thing in any other language, assuming it has implemented the specification correctly.

```
# In Ruby:
Float::NAN == Float::NAN
#=> false

// In JavaScript:
NaN == NaN
// false
```

The specification also provides a list of recommended functions, which includes:

> `isnan(x)` - a predicate for `"x is a NaN"`, equivalent to `"x ≠ x"`.

In ruby, this has been implemented as [`Float#nan?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-nan-3F):

```
Float::NAN.nan?
#=> true
```

[Under the hood, this is indeed asserting that `x != x`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/c08f7b80889b531865e74bc5f573df8fa27f2088/missing/isnan.c#L21-L31):

```
int
isnan(double n)
{
    return double_ne(n, n);
}

static int
double_ne(double n1, double n2)
{
    return n1 != n2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just ask if [`nan?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Float.html#method-i-nan-3F)

```
i = Float::NAN
i.nan?
#=> true
puts "hi" if i.nan?
#=> hi
```

Comment: Might be helpful to explain the "baffling output" (i.e. `Float::NAN == Float::NAN` being `false`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to check:

```
> i.nan?
=> true
```